# Is there an equivalent to PostgreSQL's Lateral Join in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

As the title suggests, does an equal to the lateral join exist in redshift? I haven't run into a situation where it might be necessary yet, but it seems hard to imagine replicating the functionality of a lateral join if I needed to with what I know now.

Comment: No. But there is probably another way. You need to spec out your question to include exacly what you are trying to do, your input data tables and your expected output.