# Grouping results by a set of dates in Redshift with two tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

Hope you are fine, I am trying to account the amount of observations that I have in an employee database. Tables look more or less like this:

Date_Table

| date_dt |
| --- |
| 2020-09-07 |
| 2020-09-14 |
| 2020-09-21 |

Employee_table

| login_id | effective_date | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-09-07 | 1 |
| a | 2020-09-14 | 1 |
| b | 2020-09-07 | 1 |
| b | 2020-09-14 | 0 |
| c | 2020-09-21 | 1 |

keep in mind the effective_date represents (the higher the date the most recent the change) some change (attrition, position change, what ever, those are easily filtered) being the latest the one the current status.

In the above example the date 2020-09-14 for empl_login b would be the day it stopped to be active within the table.

I want to reflect something like this:

| the_date | amount_of_employees |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-09-07 | 2 |
| 2020-09-14 | 1 |
| 2020-09-21 | 2 |

This query works perfectly fine, and provides me the correct number:

```
SELECT '2020-09-07',COUNT(DISTINCT login_id) amount_of_employees 
FROM (SELECT date_dt FROM Date_Table) AS dd,(SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login_id ORDER BY effective_date DESC) AS chk
      FROM Employee_table WHERE effective_date <=  '2020-09-07' ) AS dp

WHERE 
dp.is_active =1
AND 
dp.chk=1
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Great! This one works and gives me the right value:

| the_date | amount_of_employees |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-09-07 | 2 |

However, when I try this to build my dataset with this query:

```
SELECT dd.date_dt ,COUNT(DISTINCT login_id) amount_of_employees 
FROM (SELECT date_dt FROM Date_Table) AS dd,(SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login_id ORDER BY effective_date DESC) AS chk
      FROM Employee_table  WHERE effective_date <=  dd.date_dt ) AS dp

WHERE 
dp.is_active =1
AND 
dp.chk=1
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

I get this error message:

**Invalid operation: subquery in FROM may not refer to other relations of same query level**

I tried to investigate something like this:

https://w3coded.com/questions/672056/error-subquery-in-from-cannot-refer-to-other-relations-of-same-query-level

but didn't work or doesn't apply necessarily. May be I am not getting it

Any idea? I wouldn't like to make A lot of unions, but is a workaround.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, if you have some solution in Redshift it will be great. But since Redshift is a flavor of Postgre the solution might be close

Comment: Hi, I wasn't aware of that you are right. I Will update my labels! More reference here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563617/is-there-an-equivalent-to-postgresqls-lateral-join-in-redshift 
  Thanks a Lot

Comment: This would be the Postgre**s** solution: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=07e1c917cb8aa549ee66f0ab30f25f1b

Comment: So simple in postgre hahaha thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Amazon Redshift,but as long as your query syntax is supported, you can use a subquery to get the count, and there you'll be able to refer to the columns of the outer query like this

```
SELECT
   dt.date_dt,
   (
       SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT login_id) 
       FROM (
           SELECT 
               *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login_id ORDER BY effective_date DESC) AS rn
          FROM employee_table et
          WHERE et.effective_date <= dt.date_dt
          ORDER BY effective_date DESC
       ) t
       WHERE rn = 1 AND is_active = 1
   ) amount
FROM date_table dt
```

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for the reply. I see the logic and it should be working. However, in redshift seems not working, the error displayed is: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error. Funny enough changing 
WHERE et.effective_date <= dt.date_dt 
for 
WHERE et.effective_date <= '2020-09-07' 

runs the query. Nonetheless, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution for this:

```
SELECT dt.date_dt, COUNT(DISTINCT login_id) other_account
FROM Date_Table dt
         LEFT JOIN employee_table et ON dd.date_dt BETWEEN et.effective_date  AND et.effective_date  + (some additional interval)
WHERE et.is_active = 1 (And other where clauses)
GROUP BY 1
```

Thanks for all your support